# Youtube Data API v3 response that I've exceeded my quota but in Quota page, it says Queries per day is 0

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I tried to request [Search](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search):List and I got 403 error message as I've exceeded my quota below. But in quota's page, limits of "Queries per day" is 0.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
        "domain": "youtube.quota",
        "reason": "quotaExceeded"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After few research, I should receive 10K / day.

Please advise.